# Ansible: Breaking a retry loop conditionally

Tags: ansible

Consider executing an ansible task that checks the return value of a process with three possibilities:

1. Not started
2. Success
3. Failure

ansible should

- **pass the task** on 'success' obviously.
- **fail the task and retry** on 'not started' (handled by a retries: xx, delay: xx section)
- **fail the task without further retries*** on 'failure'

So, question basically is whether I can distinguish the 'fail and retry' and fail and do not retry' cases (`failed_when` comes a little short). Or, rephrasing, how can i break retries conditionally?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`until` is the condition to break the retries. It does not carry any information about a task failure or not. In your specific case you want to stop retries when your tasks reports a "pass" or "failure", and continue retrying while it reports "not started" (or potentially anything else depending on your condition, see below).

`failed_when` is the condition saying if your task failed or not and will be evaluated after your retries loop broke on condition or reached its max retries. In this latest case "not started" is considered a fail message.

So basically (with pseudo code)

```yaml
- name: My retry task until pass or die
  some_ansible_module:
    arg1: value1
  register: pass_or_die
  retries: 10
  delay: 10
  until: pass_or_die.resultvar in ['pass', 'failure']
  # an other option with a negative list of values
  # until: pass_or_die.resultvar not in ['not started']
  failed_when: pass_or_die.resultvar in ['failure', 'not_started']
  # once again an alternative with a negative list
  # failed_when: pass_or_die.resultvar not in ['pass']
```

Here is how I tested this to make sure it works as expected

```yaml
 ---
 - name: Pass or die
   hosts: localhost
   gather_facts: false
 
   tasks:
     - name: Retry until pass or die
       slurp:
         path: /tmp/slurp.txt
       register: slurped
       retries: 1000
       delay: 10
       until: slurped.content | b64decode not in ['not started']
       failed_when: slurped.content | b64decode not in ['pass']
```

Prior to launching the playbook, issue

```
echo -n "not started" > /tmp/slurp.txt
```

Then launch the playbook and in a separate terminal issue either

```
# To fail the task
echo -n "failure" > /tmp/slurp.txt
# To pass the task
echo -n "pass" > /tmp/slurp.txt
```

You will see the result in your playbook execution on the next retry.

You can also leave the file alone and wait it fails on its last retry (reporting "not started" which is a fail condition).